# How to load a controller when clicking a button with RubyMotion?

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby, uiviewcontroller, rubymotion

Let's say I have 2 controllers A and B.

In A I have:

```
def viewDidLoad
  super
  button = UIButton.buttonWithType UIButtonTypeRoundedRect
  button.setTitle "Open B", forState: UIControlStateNormal
  button.addTarget(self, action: :open_b, forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
  self.view.addSubview button
end

def open_b
  # ?????
end
```

In B I have another view with its own logic, which is not important.

**I want to open B when clicking the button. How should I go and do this?**

This must be dead obvious for anyone with some iOS experience, but I can't find how you're supposed to do it. Any pointers are appreciated. A solution in Objectve-C is acceptable and would get my upvote, even if I'd prefer it to be with RubyMotion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how to do it using a modal view controller:

app_delegate.rb:

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame(UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds)
    @window.rootViewController = MyViewA.alloc.init
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible
    true
  end
end
```

viewa.rb:

```
class MyViewA < UIViewController

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    button = UIButton.buttonWithType UIButtonTypeRoundedRect
    button.setTitle "Open B", forState: UIControlStateNormal
    button.frame = [[10, 50], [300, 50]]
    button.addTarget(self, action: "open_b", forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview button
  end

  def open_b
    view_b = MyViewB.alloc.init
    view_b.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController view_b, animated:true, completion:nil
  end

  def done_with_b
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated true, completion:nil
  end

end
```

viewb.rb:

```
class MyViewB < UIViewController

  attr_accessor :delegate

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    button = UIButton.buttonWithType UIButtonTypeRoundedRect
    button.setTitle "Return to A", forState: UIControlStateNormal
    button.frame = [[10, 50], [300, 50]]
    button.addTarget(self, action: "press_button", forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview button
  end

  def press_button
    delegate.done_with_b
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working fine and I like the animation. I was wondering: I managed to get something running by going `UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate.window.rootViewController = MY_CONTROLLER`, is it a bad idea?

Comment: My gut reaction to just swapping the root view controller is that it's not "the right way to do it", but I can't tell you how that might get you into trouble.

Comment: Yeah I'm having the same feeling... but so far it's working fine ^^ What if I didn't want to use a modal and just wanted to switch to another controller "completely"?

Comment: I think it all depends on the intended flow of your app.  If you never plan for the user to come back to view controller A, then it is fine to swap it out for B.  If the user should be able to select A or B at will, use a TabBarController.  If they are drilling down into a hierarchy use a NavigationController.  If they are filling out some info and then will return to your first screen then push a view controller modally.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example on how to do it: https://github.com/IconoclastLabs/rubymotion_cookbook/tree/master/ch_2/11_navbarbuttons

Specifically your method would be using this portion:

```
def performAdd
    @secondary_controller = SecondaryController.alloc.init
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(@secondary_controller, animated:'YES')
end
```

I highly recommend referring to this repo (yeah it's mine), whenever you need some basics!

http://iconoclastlabs.github.com/rubymotion_cookbook/

Hope that does it for ya!

Comment: The value for `animated:` should be `true` and not `'YES'`.  `'YES'` works but for the reason that the string is true as far as booleans go since it is not nil.  But, changing it to `'NO'` would not have the desired effect since that is still true in the boolean sense.

Comment: @vacawama yes, you are correct.  This was written a LONG time ago, and should be updated. Please do a pull request!  We'll happily receive your contribution to the open source project.